# Flutter english_words unused_import error

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I'm getting the above error:

> Unused import: package:english_words/english_words.dart

I don't understand why I am getting an error.
What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is referring you didn't use the package. You can remove the import (line 1) if you dont use the package on this file. Or you can ignore it for now.

You can find more about [linter-rules](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules) and [flutter_lints](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints).

Comment: Adding to that, the message "Unused import" is only a warning, not an error.